# I can't see an infinite loop but my game still freezes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, infinite-loop, freeze

I have some code for an enemy in a Unity c# game. The code has a function that decreases health and some code connected to a trigger that calls the function using `Invoke()`. The `Invoke` method is stored within a while loop so that it executes when health is greater than 0. The script is below.

I can run the game, but whenever the enemy enters the trigger the game freezes. This is usually due to an infinite loop but to my eyes it looks right. Is there something I'm missing?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Base : MonoBehaviour {

public float Health = 100f;
public float AttackSpeed = 2f;

//If enemy touches the base 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
        while(Health > 0f){
            Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
            //call attack funtion in x seconds
            Invoke("enemyAttack", 2.0f);
        }
    }
}

//Enemy attack function that can be used with Invoke
void enemyAttack(){
    Health -= Enemy.Damage;
    Debug.Log ("Base health at: " + Health);
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Load Lose Screen when Base health reaches 0
    if (Health <= 0){
        Application.LoadLevel("Lose Screen");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning Enemy.Damage? I see you've passed 2.0f to the Invoke but not where you're assigning Enemy.Damage to this parameter.

Comment: Enemy.Damage is a public static float called damage that is in another script called Enemy

Comment: sounds like you need to use the debugger and take your time to step through and evaluate all variables to see if you can pinpoint the issue

Comment: An infinite loop doesn't provoke the program to freeze, but to crash. The freezing is provoked by loops taking too long, usually in 1-thread applications (the GUI cannot be updated before the loop has finished). The solution is easy: multithreading (well... or making the loop(s) quicker).

Comment: Enemy.Damage is initialized to 10

Comment: `while(Health > 0f){` is **bad** in combination with the `Invoke()`, which may take a while to execute. There's your infinite loop right there.

Comment: The while loop looks suspicious anyway, as it will cause your character to die whenever he touches an enemy. Also the `2.0f` means that your invoke is delayed ([see the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)), so the while loop just continuously queues up the function calls without ever actually reducing the players health (thus you get your infinite loop)

Comment: Yikes, if the 2.0f is a delay to your function call, there's your problem. @UnholySheep nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Invoke()` is being called over and over, queuing up. You should use a coroutine here instead.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
        if (Health > 0f){
            Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
            StartCoroutine (enemyAttack ());
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator enemyAttack () {
    while (Health > 0f) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
        Health -= Enemy.Damage;
        Debug.Log ("Base health at: " + Health);
    }
}
```

Comment: But once the coroutine is started, it goes on draining the health every 2 seconds *forever* until the health reaches zero. After the damage-causing object has exited the collision trigger, it should stop draining health (it doesn't directly say so, but that's the most logical thing I can think of)

Comment: The `if(Health>0f)` in `OnCollisionEnter2D` is kinda unnecessary (as the Coroutine repeats the check anyway and the update function terminates the game if health drops below 0 ). Also The logic still seems off, as the player dies once he touches an enemy (and has no apparent way of stopping it)

Comment: This answers the question asked. His code is designed to drain the health every 2 seconds. The `if` in the `OnCollisionEnter2D` would prevent creating the coroutine if it's not needed.

Comment: @unholy sheep, the player doesn't die when he touches an enemy. The problem now is that even after an enemy has been destroyed the coroutine keeps running and draining health until it reaches 0

Comment: @lucasRHCP You need to call `StopCoroutine ("enemyAttack")` when the condition for stopping `enemyAttack ()` has been met.